# c++: address to string constant

Tags: c++, string, constants, memory-address

Can I get the address of an object as a string constant in g++? Example:

```
struct s { } x;
```

If `&x == 1234`, then I need `"1234"` in my code.

**EDIT**:

By string constant I meant that I need that constant string at compile- or link-time. I need to embed it in inline assembly code like this:

```
template < typename U >
struct T {
  static int x;
  void f () {
    asm (".word " some-expression-containing-(&x));
  }
};
```

I don't know a way to construct the mangled name with a preprocessor macro, so I asked this question.

The solution doesn't need to be portable, g++ is sufficient.

The address itself is known at compile- or link-time though, as it would work to examine the assembly output and put in the mangled name into the inline assembly instruction.

Comment: The address of `x` isn't (necessarily) know at compile-time.

Comment: Just write an object file that contains the name and look at the export tables of the produced object file using `nm`. This will show you the mangled name of the object.

Comment: @Konrad: My problem is that the object is of a templated class, and I need several instantiations of the code that produces different addresses for different template parameters. It wouldn't be nice to have to look up every imaginable mangled name in an object file.

Comment: Can you not do that by having your inline assembly within a templated method then?

Comment: @awoodland: I re-edited my question to clarify where the problem occurs.

Comment: FWIW, asking how to get a string constant instead of how to get the address of a variable for use in asm is an example of the [XY problem](http://tinyurl.com/meta-xy).

Comment: You're right. At least, everyone here seems to agree that the original question (string constant of address) does not seem to have a solution in c++, and as almost every problem occurs in the context of another problem that needs to be solved, I had to fall back to that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template<class U>
struct T {
  static int x;
  void f () {
    asm (".word %0" : "m" (&x));
  }
};
```

This [works](http://codepad.org/YmMnX2p4) for me in [g++](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.1/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Extended-Asm).

Comment: This might be the solution, but it fails to compile in my case: `asm ("brsl $lr, %0" : "m" (&buf<prg>::obj.store));` (where `brsl` is a "call" instruction on powerpc) leads to `error: lvalue required in asm statement` and `error: output operand constraint lacks '='`. Perhaps I'm missing something simple...

Comment: @Thomas: Looks like you need to [modify](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.1/gcc/Modifiers.html#Modifiers) the constraint.  Unfortunately, I'm very bad at writing asm and only mediocre at reading it (and only that when I have lots of docs at hand).

Comment: @Roger: Hm... I'm also not experienced with assembly, I'm now trying out some combinations of modifiers and constraints. I wonder why g++ recognizes `%0` as "output" operand, it should be an input. Perhaps something has to be changed when using intel instead of AT&T syntax (if this difference is relevant to powerpc)?

Comment: `asm ("brsl $lr, %0" :: "rm" (&buf<prg>::obj.store));` compiles, but gives some strange warnings

Comment: @thomas: perhaps you should try changing the constraint to `p` instead of `rm`

Answer (score 4):

I wonder why would you need that... but you can do this:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <cstddef> //for ptrdiff_t
....
stringstream ss;
ss << reinterpret_cast<ptrdiff_t>(&x);
```

`ss.str()` now contains your desired string

***edit:*** If you want to do this compile-time... erm... I'll dare assume ***it's impossible***?

Comment: int isn't very portable, ptrdiff_t might be a better choice

Comment: I need the address at compile time. Needed to write something as `asm (".word " some-expression-that-contains-an-address), and the name of the object would have a difficult mangled name, so I don't see a way to construct it with a macro.

Comment: You don't need to cast; `operator <<` is overloaded for pointers.

Comment: @Oli: The overload prints in Hex, no?

Comment: @Oli: In this case the address is known at compile time (it should also be possible to have it as a template parameter: `template < s* adr > struct t { }; t<&x> o;`)

Comment: You might be able to figure out offsets from predictable places (e.g. the top of a stack frame) at compile time, but it's rather fragile to say the least. What's the real problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @awoodland: Please see my edit in the original post: I'm trying to pass the address of an object (of a templated class) with long mangled name to a piece of inline assembly code.

Comment: @Thomas: No, it's known at link-time, but not at compile-time.

Comment: @Oli: link-time would be okay, too. I only need correct assembly code to be generated that includes the address of the object.

Comment: @Thomas: Link-time is a bit late to be generating asm.

Comment: @Roger: That sounds reasonable, so there might be no solution to generate a string constant - but then, how could I rewrite the code to use the address of the object in my assembly code (without having to look up every possible mangled name in the object file and modify the code)?

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
asm(".word x")
```

(it will work only for file-scope variables symbols as only they potentially get a symbol table entry). It's not constant expression, but the address is anyway not known until the program is fully linked.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to achieve - but as the mangled name of x is very complicated (and not known to me, because the class of x is templated and there might be several x for different template parameters), I thought that it might be easier to directly provide the address as a string constant.

Answer (score 0):

In C, you could do this, but, in C, as you are using `char *`'s as your strings, you need something like this:

```
printf("%i-%i", &string[0], &string[strlen(string) - 1]);
```

That prints the range of memory the string is in, istead of the starting adress.

Answer (score 0):

The error output operand constraint lacks `=` is because haven't operator `=` before of the operator out `m`. Take `=m`